# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history' when using backend random_uniform

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing a WGAN-GP in Keras where I calculate the random weighted average of two tensors.

```
def random_weighted_average(self, generated, real):
    alpha = K.random_uniform(shape=K.shape(real))
    diff = keras.layers.Subtract()([generated, real])
    return keras.layers.Add()([real, keras.layers.Multiply()([alpha, diff])])
```

This is how it's used. It throws the error once I try to create the `discriminator_model`.

```
averaged_samples = self.random_weighted_average(
    generated_samples_for_discriminator, 
    real_samples)
averaged_samples_out = self.discriminator(averaged_samples)

discriminator_model = Model(
    inputs=[real_samples, generator_input_for_discriminator],
    outputs=[
        discriminator_output_from_real_samples,
        discriminator_output_from_generator, 
        averaged_samples_out
    ])
```

My backend is TensorFlow. When I use `alpha` in the last line I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'`

I tried swapping `alpha` out for both `real` and `generated` to see if it had to do with the backend tensor and that was the case (the error disappeared). So what could be causing this issue? I need a random uniformly sampled tensor with the shape of `real` or `generated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom operations that use backend function need to be wrapped around a `Layer`. If you don't have any trainable weights, as in your case, the simplest approach is to use a `Lambda` layer:

```
def random_weighted_average(inputs):
  generated, real = inputs
  alpha = K.random_uniform(shape=K.shape(real))
  diff = generated - real
  return real + alpha * diff
averaged_samples = Lambda(random_weighted_average)([generated_for_discriminator, real_samples])
```